# ¿Cómo compilar y correr un programa de C++ en el terminal de Mac?

Tags: c++, macos

El nombre de mi archivo se llama "Programa #3", creo que tiene algo que ver el espacio en el nombre del programa, ya que no lo encuentra al usar el comando "g++" para compilarlo.

Answer (score -1):

Muy simple, haz lo siguiente:
Una vez estés en la terminal y ubicado en la dirección en la que se encuentra tu archivo (código fuente) implemente...

```
g++ nombre_archivo.cpp -o nombre_de_ejecutable
```

y para compilar usa

```
./nombre_de_ejecutable
```

Listo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Eduardo!
El problema radicaba en que al tener un espacio el nombre del archivo, este tenia que encerrarlo entre comillas para que pudiera generarme el nombre del ejecutable